# How to parse time in natural language?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, time

There are several ways to parse time and dates in natural language ([`parsedatetime`](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime) being a typical one). These libraries are intended to parse the time as in 'time of the day' (`15 minutes from now` for instance).

I am looking at parsing **time spans** and provide their equivalent in a single unit (say, seconds). An example would be `1min` (the answer is `60`) or `30 seconds` (the answer is `30`).

Since I will control the format of the time strings I could write my own very basic parser based on a regex expression (such as `(\d+)\ (\w+)`) and make sure that I always use a `<number> <unit>` format, with a strict (and short) list of `<unit>`.  Before reinventing the wheel I was wondering if there is not a more standard approach?

Comment: Have a look at a module called arrow.

Comment: @DeepSpace: I use `arrow` all the time (and have been advertising it on SO as well) but I was under the impression that it handles only dates (and associated times), and not time spans as in my case?

Comment: @DeepSpace: your comment made me also look at `pendulum` and `delorean` but they seem to lack this "time span" parsing as well (which is probably OK as they manipulate dates)

Comment: Are you looking for an application (any programming language?), algorithms, or methods ?